# CSS Opacity With Parent Object

Tags: javascript, css, inheritance, styling

Hi I wanted to make have a popup such that the background has an opacity of 80% but the inside child objects do not inherit this property and remain 100% opaque and visible. How would I script the css or javascript to make this appear? Something like:

```
<div style=opacity:80>
     <div style=opacity:100>
          I want to make this text to not be partially transparent due from style inheritance
     </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks for any help in advance

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind! I found a very simple solution:

```
<div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)">
    <div style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0); margin: 15px">
         This text is 100% OPAQUE with a white background and 80% opaque outer background! YAY!
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Found this method from inspecting Twitter's source code

Comment: rgba is HTML 5 only, you'll have issues with IE 7 which is unfortunately, not dead yet.

Comment: rgba is not HTML 5, it's CSS.

Comment: It's either this, or a transparent PNG background, if you want to keep the HTML nice and semantic. (Assuming you replace the inner `div` with a `p` element or something similar, that is.)

Comment: yea i tried out the transparent png, but when you change opacity levels using, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
<div style='position:relative;width:WWW; height:HHH;'>
     <div style='opacity:80; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:WWW; height:HHH;'> <!-- cover -->
     <div>
          I want to make this text to not be partially transparent due from style inheritance
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is how all of the libraries do modal pop ups.  Good answer.

Comment: that is one way i have done it but look what i just found out from twitter's source code below!

Comment: I know, but in reality sometimes there is no other workaround.

Comment: That's funny I receive -1 for this, every well known plugin I see is doing this :-\

Comment: They use this method for Masks on backgrounds in a lot of libraries, it is a good work around until browsers that do not support CSS 3 are gone.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities here, in order of flexibility before simplicity:

**Method 1:**

Create an unstyled DIV (DIV #1).  Create a second DIV (DIV #2) inside it with the background, borders, and opacity set as you like. Create a third DIV beside DIV #2, using relative positioning to place it on top of DIV #1.  Put your content inside this DIV!

This method doesn't work well because stretching the content DIV doesn't inherently stretch the background DIV.

**Method 2:**

Create one single DIV, but instead of using Opacity use RGBA values.  Simply put, with RGBA you specify RGB values, and then an alpha (transparency) level, for instance:

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
```

You can use RGBA for the background, borders, text, you name it - and simply declaring the child element's color to be a non-transparent value is enough to prevent the transparency's inheritance.

For images, it's relatively simple to add an alpha layer to a PNG with most image editing software.  Consult your manual.

A little crossbrowser shenaniganza is required to make IE8 and earlier like this, but that's another question (and answer.)